# Domain name with a dot and Ctrl+Enter

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, url

When I write `superuser` in Firefox address bar then pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> keys, Firefox goes to the `superuser.com`. But when I write for example `math.stackexchange` that has a dot in its domain name and then pressing the same keys, Firefox doesn't add `.com` to the domain name. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The "bug" has already been sent to mozilla: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/954076 but there seem to be no answer...

I think their code just checks if the typed string contains a dot or not to add "www." and ".com".

You can just disable this option in `http://about:config` or change the prefix/suffix with the `browser.fixup...` parameters